# Constructor not initialising variables

Tags: java, constructor

Here is the output(for my example): 
"0
18"
but normally the object "checks" of the class Checks initializes the variable `n` of the class `Checks` at 18 but this is not happening.

```
public class Connect6 {
    int n;

    public Connect6(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }


    Checks checks = new Checks(n);


    public void place() {
        Terminal.printLine(checks.getN());
        Terminal.printLine(n);
    }
}
```

and this is the Check class ( the class `main` just initializes an object `Connect6` and calls the method `place`):

```
public class Checks {
    int n;
    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }
    public Checks(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
```

Comment: Where it initializing class Connect6 and calling method place ?

Comment: Class main, that I didn't post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Checks checks = new Checks(n);` is executed before the body of your `Connect6` constructor, so `n` is still 0 at the time. You should create the `Checks` instance inside your `Connect6` constructor, after `n` is initialized.

Change

```
public Connect6(int n) {
    this.n = n;
}


Checks checks = new Checks(n);
```

to

```
private Checks checks;
public Connect6(int n) {
    this.n = n;
    this.checks = new Checks(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type `int n;`, it's value is not `null` it's `0`.

Have a look at [Java specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), at `Default Values` paragraph.

Default `int` value is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

checks object was initialized before constructor call

Correct code should looks like this:

```
public class Connect6 {
    int n;
    Checks checks;

    public Connect6(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        this.checks = new Checks(n);
    }

    public void place() {
        Terminal.printLine(checks.getN());
        Terminal.printLine(n);
    }
}
```